# bootstrap-wysiwyg: text dropping doesn't work

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-wysiwyg

Does anyone know why text dropping into the [bootstrap-wysiwyg editor](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) doesn't work? Copy/pasting works fine but selecting text, dragging it over the editor and dropping it has no effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the actual editor is a `<div>` element and not a `<textarea>`, as you might expect.

Drag and drop is handled by the browser on a textarea, but a div is not really a control element.